# How to manually change the x-axis label in ggplot?

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, label, axis-labels

I want to change the x-axis labels of my ggplot. Below is my sample code

```
DF <- data.frame(seq(as.Date("2001-04-01"), to= as.Date("2001-8-31"), by="day"),
                 A = runif(153, 0,10))
colnames(DF)<- c("Date", "A")
ggplot(DF, aes(x = Date, y = A))+
  geom_line()+
scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b", date_breaks = "month", name = "Month")
```

I tried `scale_x_discrete(breaks = c(0,31,60,90,120), labels = c("Jan", "Feb","Mar","Apr","May"))` with no success. I know my data is from April but would like to change the labels pretending that its from January.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `scale_x_date` but pass a vector of date into `breaks` and a character vector in `labels` of the same length as described in the official documentation (https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_date.html):

```r
ggplot(DF,aes(x = Date, y = A, group = 1))+
  geom_line()+
  scale_x_date(breaks = seq(ymd("2001-04-01"),ymd("2001-08-01"), by = "month"),
                   labels = c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May"))
```

### [image]

**EDIT: Substract months using `lubridate`**

Alternatively, using `lubridate`, you can substract 3 months and use this new date variable to plot your data:

```r
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

DF %>% mutate(Date2 = Date %m-% months(3))%>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Date2, y = A))+
  geom_line()+
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b", date_breaks = "month", name = "Month")
```

[image]

Does it look what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: sort of but not exactly. How about changing the labels to a completely different pattern such as `labels = c("Nov","Dec","Jan","Feb","Mar")`

Comment: I think it is easier to change your date format before the plot than trying to modify individually each labels in `scale_x_date`. For your new pattern, use `months(5)`.

Comment: I tried the code, i am getting warning regarding missing data.

Comment: Yes, because some values get to NA when substracting values. I edited my code. Adding `%m-%` will exactly calculate the right day for each values and will remove warnings.

Comment: Note that substracting days is not perfect as all months does not have same numbers of days (especially february) so somehow, you are incorporating some errors

Comment: My apologizes, I finally found a solution pretty simple without to twisted to much data. I edited my answer. It should be what you are looking for now. Let me know if it is working